# Why RDLC local report chart has different graphic with RDL(SSRS)?

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc, reportviewer, report-designer

I know the basic difference between RDLC and RDL, both almost the same uses XML schemas just different designer platform (SQL and Visual Studio). I wondering to know why both have a different graphic, like chart interface, chart style and anything else. I would like to use RDLC but the graphic looks older than RDL(SSRS), assumed SSRS 2016. 
Is it possible if I have RDLC reporting like SSRS contents?